# Edge Compatibility with iframe causes reload instead of wanted behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe in my react app that links to an external site where people can fill out a form to sign-up for service. On chrome and firefox this iframe works fine, if you fill out the form itll allow you to click next to move to the next set of form fields to fill out. however on Edge, ive noticed that no matter what you do, once you hit "next" to go to the next form field, it will breifly go to the next page, however it will "refresh" so to speak, and back up to the first form field. effectively keeping you from filling out required fields.

is there a way to ensure browser compatibility here? ill note that the external site uses a lot of JQuery script to perform its necessary functions. but it shouldnt be that as that code also has a script tag that imports the JQuery CDN so it should function correctly.

Comment: I figured out the iframe needed a secure connection to the site in order to work. the connection i was using was http, so one little 's' missing is what was causing the problem, once i connected via https the form started working like normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `iFrame` tag needs a secured connection, Was using an http connection, the reason i could not move forward was because the page that was loaded needs a secured connection to move forward.